# Philco 90 - What do the four dials do?

Tags: wood

I'm posting this here hoping that other DIY'ers might be able to help - not sure if Home Improvement is the right place, but this seems the closest on Stack Exchange.

I'm constructing an antique radio out of scraps I can find on the Internet. I'm not sure what to make the dials do in the Philco 90.

Top dial - radio channel tuning

Right dial - volume

Middle dial - tone(?)

Left dial - not sure at all.. AM/FM? FM didn't come about until mid-1930s. Anachronism?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at these [operating instructions for a Philco 90](http://www.renovatedradios.com/downloads.html), the top knob is indeed the station selection knob, the bottom left is tone, bottom right is volume, and the center is the on/off switch.